PBI - Year total value does not reflect the DAX I wrote
Screen shot of my Dax and Table
All past data in actuals are finalized. If I only show actuals data, the full year graph looks off due to the rest of the year being 0.
So, we wanted to set if future months are 0, actuals + forecast numbers. However, when filtered on full year value, it is still showing me only actuals numbers. Any idea on how to fix this?
DAX - IF([Total CY Actual]=0,[Total CY Actual]+[Total AprForecast],[Total CY Actual])
I was expecting full year number being the actuals + forecast number. Drilling down by month works, but full year is off.

maybe you can create another measure
measure= sumx(values(month),[actual+FC])
